# freeCodeCamp JavaScript course for beginners

Tags: javascript

I'm following this free course on JavaScript and came across a line of code that has me puzzled.

```
const sum2 = (function(){
    return function sum2 (...args){
        return args.reduce((a,b) => a + b , 0)  
    }
})();
console.log(sum2(1,2,3,4,5)); //result 15, which comes from 1+2+3+4+5
```

My question concerns the `return args.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0` line, I am wondering what the `a` and `b` stand for, how do they cause my values to get summed?

Comment: They are just arbitrary argument names. Try reading [the documentation for `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That my friend is an arrow function. The equivalent would be:

```js
args.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b
} , 0)
```

a and b in this case is an accumulator and the current value which gets passed on.

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on this part

```
1| function sum2 (...args){
2|     return args.reduce((a,b) => a + b , 0)  
3| }
```

first, args on line 2 is an array containing all the arguments.

second, the reduce function basically takes all values inside an array and returning a single one based on some relationship between them.
a represents the current value, and b is the next value in the array.
in the first iteration a is the first value in the array and b is the second number in the array.
then a becomes the relation between the first and the second number and b is the third number in the array, etc..

that's how you get 15

Comment: Thank you, that makes things clear :)